# How to Customise android Os For supporting regional launguages

Tags: android, native-code

How to customize Android Os for supporting regional languages???

I was wondering what the feasibility would be for creating a custom Android build

and deploying it on a currently available device on the market ....????

Opinion about which language,Sdk,other things  i need to use .All are welcome

I don't know where to start .I need Advice from experts

Thanks for your valuable time........

Regards,
Kariyachan

Answer (score 0):

Regional Language, like : German, Swedish, French etc?

If yes, that's your link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

It's quite easy in Android.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,I wondering Is there any way to add support for regional languages like English in android Os, to run whole system in a particular regional language

Comment: The whole system runs in a particular language, chosen by the user. Your application should provide the translations necessary for the user to understand it. By Regional language, do you mean dialects? I think you are just limited to the languages provided by the Firmware, nothing else.

Comment: No I am talking about Android Os -:).I need to customize Os.So that user will have option to run his System in that particular language say 'Italian' .It must be supported in device, like English does.Then I can change to Italian by goto settings ---> language and keyboard settings --> Select language . where should I begin...??. Thanks for your time

Comment: You want to change the system language from your APP?

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize Android, first you need to get the source from [source.android.com](http://source.android.com). Then you can add translations or make any other improvements.

After that you can just build your custom Android or ask to contribute the project itself.

For applications, special localization work is required within application resources.